# Generate heap dump without JDK - SIGQUIT to application?

Tags: java, process, heap-memory, dump

any idea how do generate a java heapdump without JDK?
I'm able to obtain the processid but I don't have access to the machine directly and there's no JDK installed.

> You can alternatively use the JVM parameter -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
>   and send a SIGQUIT signal (-3 kill for Unix and Ctrl-Break for
>   Windows) to the running Java process – the signal will also create a
>   heapdump without aborting the JVM

Is there an easier way? and how can I send a SIGQUIT to the process?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you still have access via SSH/telnet you could use:

```
 kill -QUIT <pid>
```

as you described in you quotation.

Other option in to access the application via JMX, i.e. jconsole or jvisialvm

To use JMX you need enabled JMX via the command line of the application

Comment: I'm on Windows, anything I could use there? It's just Windows and JRE (no JDK).

Comment: Well, I see, there is no SIGQUIT on WIndows. So I think you have the following options:  
1) if you have access to the application command window on WIndows - then press ctrl-break in it   2) implement a custom JMX server in your code, access it via HTTP and code a custom function to print stack trace   3) install JDK (if you can)